# Changing remove directory of ftp to poll using spring integration ftp

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I'm developing an app which downloads the files from ftp server. However the ftp folder may differ during each run. The ftp folder to be polled is provided by the user.

I noticed the spring documentation mentions remote-directory-expression use but I'm not sure how can I use this for the parameters supplied by a user.

Inputs please.

Answer (score 0):

The expression can reference any bean via `@someBean.someMethod()`.

You might find it easier, however, to use the FTP outbound gateway to get specific files.